# Source for the Usage of "Kabbalah"

Tags: history, sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, etymology

What are the earliest sources that refer to Jewish mysticism in particular as "kabblah".

---

(Preferably the answer should include an indication that the word was associated with this in particular, rather than just being used for mysticism as an example of things which are received by tradition).

Comment: As opposed to being called "מעשה המרכבה?"

Comment: @Mefaresh Yes. BTW Rambam understands that "maa'sa merkava" refers to metaphysics.

Comment: interesting can you quote me that rambam?

Comment: what is the Hebrew word for metaphysics? What words does the Rambam use?

Comment: Hil YHT 2:11: דְּבָרִים אֵלּוּ שֶׁאָמַרְנוּ בְּעִנְיָן זֶה בִּשְׁנֵי פְּרָקִים אֵלּוּ כְּמוֹ טִפָּה מִן הַיָּם הֵם מִמַּה שֶּׁצָּרִיךְ לְבָאֵר בְּעִנְיָן זֶה. וּבֵאוּר כָּל הָעִקָּרִים שֶׁבִּשְׁנֵי פְּרָקִים אֵלּוּ הוּא הַנִּקְרָא מַעֲשֵׂה מֶרְכָּבָה see his discussion until there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ramban (12th-13th century) towards the end of his introduction to his commentary on Chumash uses the term in what seems to be a clearly "kabbalistic" context:

> וכן יכתבו השם הגדול שהזכרתי כולו רצוף, ויתחלק לתיבות של שלש שלש אותיות לחלוקים אחרים רבים, כפי השמוש לבעלי הקבלה
>
> (my attempt at a translation) And similarly the great Name which I mentioned (the 72-letter name) is entirely contiguous, and it can be divided into groups of three letter words, in many permutations, as its usage is knows to the masters of the *kabbalah*.

Answer (score 4):

The [Sefer Hachinuch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_ha-Chinuch) (13th cent.) seems to refer to students of Jewish mysticism as "the mekubalim" (mitsva 98):

> משרשי המצוה. שצונו השם יתברך להיות נר דולק בבית המקדש להגדלת הבית לכבוד ולתפארת בעיני הרואים, כי כן דרך בני איש להתכבד בבתיהם בנרות דולקים, וכל ענין ההגדלה בו כדי שיכניס האדם בלבו כשיראהו מורא וענוה. וכבר אמרנו (במצוה טז) כי במעשה הטוב תכשר הנפש. וכל זה סובב על היסוד הבנוי לנו כי הכל נגזר מצד המקבלים עם היותי מאמין באמת כי יש למקבלים בענינים אלה חכמות נכבדות וסודות נפלאים. ואולם גם אנחנו נכתב הנראה כפשוטן של דברים, והכל לשם שמים.

Similarly (#324):

> והאמנתי כי יש אל המקבלים סודות נפלאים במצות הלולב ושלשת המינים

[R. Bachye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahya_ben_Asher) (13th-14th century) uses the expression "mekubalim" frequently in his Torah commentary to refer to students of Jewish mysticism. E.g. Genesis (1: 2) and Leviticus (23: 40).

His contemporary  [R. Menachem Recanati](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menahem_Recanati) uses this expression as well. E.g. Leviticus (7: 19).

[Rashbash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_ben_Simon_Duran) (d. 1467) refers to students of Jewish mysticism as "the mekubalim" (Shu”t Rashbash ([§189](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1380&st=&pgnum=86), not numbered, begins “כי”) as does his son, R. Zemach (Shu"t Yachin U'boaz [vol. 1 intro. to ch. 135](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1949&st=&pgnum=467&hilite=)).

Comment: Chinuch seems to say m'kab'lim, not m'kubalim. (Which former makes more sense, anyway.)